# Accessing the rewritten URI in a php script

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2

So I have a .htaccess file which is performing a rewrite from /testscript1.php/testvar1/testvar2 to 
/testscript2.php/testvar3/testvar4 
(this is an over simplification but you get the idea).

Now though in my testscript2.php script when i access the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable i see /testscript1.php/testvar1/testvar2 rather than /testscript2.php/testvar3/testvar4 which is what I am looking for. i.e $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] contains the uri before the rewrite.

My question is simply, is there a way to access the rewritten uri?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `phpinfo()` to get a view on what `$_SERVER` looks like on a rewritten page. Apache supplies quite a lot of info that may be useful.

On my test server, I get the following which may help you:

```
$_SERVER["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]
$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
```

I would expect that at least one or a combination of those should be able to reliably give you the information you're looking for.

Cheers.

Comment: I had a look at phpinfo and turns out PATH_INFO has the information i need. Thanks a mil.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using the *path info* to pass an additional path, you can strip that suffix from *PHP_SELF*:

```
substr(parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PHP_URL_PATH), -strlen($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']))
```

Or simply use *SCRIPT_NAME* since *PHP_SELF* = *SCRIPT_NAME* + *PATH_INFO*. Just take a look at the various values in [`$_SEVER`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server).